# "The pills might have helped him, if only he'd taken them regularly" necessarily means "he" didn't?

Tags: subjunctives

Below is the sentence I am asking about.

> The pills **might** have helped him, if only he'd taken them regularly.

I think the sentence has a structure typical of a subjunctive.
So does the sentence necessarily mean that in reality he had not taken the pills regularly until the moment of the crisis in the past and failed to overcome the health crisis well?

Or, is there any way that he had actually taken the pills regularly so he survived the crisis without huge trouble due to it?

I am asking whether that sentence is necessarily based on the opposite statement of the fact the speaker currently knows happened, or whether there can be a case the speaker doesn't know the exact facts and is just stating his or her own opinion.

Comment: **if only** necessarily means that the act did not occur.  *If only I had bet  my money on #2!*  Now in your example there's some ambiguity. We don't know if he *ever* took a single pill, or if he took them erratically. All we know is that he did not take them regularly.  The inference most would draw is that he did take them, but did so erratically.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you very much for the kind, clear answer. If I may ask you more, what if just ***if*** instead of ***if only*** were used in the sentence? Does it still necessarily mean that he didn't take the pills regularly and he was not able to get well through the health crisis?

Comment: The listener would infer from **if he had taken them regularly** in your sample sentence that the speaker has reason to believe that he had not taken them regularly.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you very much again. I think the fact the listener would infer so from ***if he had taken them regularly*** may involve factors outside the expression itself when it is said. I would like to ask you if the expression ***The pills might have helped him, if he'd taken them regularly*** itself only by its literal or grammatical sense must mean **he didn't take them regularly** in fact. If a speaker says that just neutrally not meaning he didn't take the pills regularly, is it grammatically wrong?

Comment: You cannot judge the *if*-clause in isolation.  Its meaning is relative to the matrix clause and the meaning of the sentence as a whole is context-dependent. There is no meaning without context. *The pills might have helped him, if he'd taken them regularly.* could be put forward as a possible explanation for why a particular person lived to the age of 106.  Or it could be said when a person died too young. If he'd taken his pills, he might have lived longer. But that is not to say that a listener wouldn't infer something from the sentence, without a context. Inference assumes a context.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you for the explanation, sir. I was just wondering if I really can never ever use ***The pills might have helped him, if he'd taken them regularly*** in just a neutral, indicative mood, not in a subjunctive mood. Do you mean it is used in  a indicative mood by ***"The pills might have helped him, if he'd taken them regularly" could be put forward as a possible explanation for why a particular person lived to the age of 106***?

Comment: Modal **might** is expresses confident conjecture, and **if** declares nothing; it expresses a condition which could be true or false, or a supposition.